# Is it good to duplicate jpa entities for business objects?

Tags: java

I have a design/architectural problem:

I've started developing a java web application. I thought of using 3 layers: a persistence layer (with jpa and hibernate), a business layer and a presentation layer. My problem now is: 
the jpa entities would make the model but can or may I use the entities as business objects?

Is this a practice? My common sense says I shouldn't, but then, I need to duplicate these entities as business objects?

Finally, I'd like the presentation layer to be really decoupled from the other layers. While using spring mvc with jsp at first, I'd like. if it's suitable, at some moment to switch to javascript-based application that communicates with the backend through rest requests.

Comment: Of course you should use them in your business layer (and even in the presentation layer). Why wouldn't you? You would lose almost all the advantages of JPA by not using entities in the business layer: lazy loading, transparent persistence, etc. And all you would get is code duplication and boilerplate.

Comment: In a recent project I worked on we regretted having hibernate entities in our presentation layer when suddenly we had to split out our backend to a service for several other projects. Needless to say the job of tearing this apart and seperate it again afterwards wasn't very pleasant. But until then having the entities in all layers was very convenient. Just think hard about your decision.. you know loose coupling and all that..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Outside the persistence context, the JPA Entities are like simple POJOs. It is legal to use them in business code (actually, as hinted by JB Nizet, you usually ALWAYS use them in your business layer without DAO). If it is tightly related to the Entity, you can even add business logic into your JPA beans. Nevertheless, it will be harder to read and understand what the code does. But if you have a reason to do that - there is nothing illegal. It all comes down to software design practices and what you need most.

When you want to change your app into the REST-powered service, it is not difficult. You will have to change the Servlet you are currently running your app with for a `JAX-RS` or other framework `Servlet` which will handle `HTTP` requests in a `REST` manner for you. It is done in `web.xml`. Then, you will place your html-pages in any place, where it is accesible for the remote hosts, and connect them to your REST-service with the Javascript AJAX or sth. You should take care of CORS then.